# Borel canteli for not i.i.d r.v

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $A_n$ be events s.t $\sum P(A_n) =\infty$. Denote
> $$ \alpha = \limsup \frac{(\sum P(A_n))^2}{\sum _{1\leq m\neq n \leq \infty} P(A_n \cap A_m)}$$ Prove $P(A_n i.o)\geq \alpha $ 
> You can use: $$P (X > 0) ≥\frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]}$$ for X non negetive and gets only values in $\mathbb{Z}$

I managed to prove the hint but I dont know how to solve the problem.

Thank you,

Comment: What does $A_n=k$ mean?

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: Do you mean $$\alpha = \limsup_{N\to\infty} \frac{(\sum_{n\leq N} P(A_n))^2}{\sum _{1\leq m\neq n \leq N} P(A_n \cap A_m)}$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the random variables

$$ X_N = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \mathbf{1}_{A_k} \qquad\text{and}\qquad X_{\infty} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_k}. $$

This $X_N$ related to the quantity $\alpha$ via the following observation:

$$ a_N := \frac{( \sum_{k \leq N} \mathbf{P}(A_k) )^2}{\sum_{1\leq j\neq k\leq N} \mathbf{P}(A_j \cap A_k)} = \frac{\mathbf{E}[X_N]^2}{\mathbf{E}[X_N^2] - \mathbf{E}[X_N]} $$

Now fix a positive integer $m$, and write $x_+ = \max\{0, x\}$ for the positive part of $x$. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(X_N > m)
= \mathbf{P}((X_N - m)_+ > 0)
\geq \frac{\mathbf{E}[(X_N - m)_+]^2}{\mathbf{E}[(X_N - m)_+^2]}
\geq \frac{(\mathbf{E}[X_N] - m)_+^2}{\mathbf{E}[X_N^2]}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

The second step follows from the inequality given as a hint, and the last step follows from Jensen's inequality applied to the  convex function $x \mapsto x_+$ and the trivial observation $X_N \geq (X_N - m)_+$. To relate this lower bound with $\alpha$, we rewrite this bound as

\begin{align*}
&a_N \frac{(\mathbf{E}[X_N] - m)_+^2}{\mathbf{E}[X_N]^2} \frac{\mathbf{E}[X_N^2] - \mathbf{E}[X_N]}{\mathbf{E}[X_N^2]} \\
&\quad = a_N \left( 1 - \frac{m}{\mathbf{E}[X_N]}\right)_+^2 \frac{1}{1 - \mathbf{E}[X_N]/\mathbf{E}[X_N^2]}.
\end{align*}

We note that $\mathbf{E}[X_N] = \sum_{k\leq N}\mathbf{P}(A_k) \to \infty$ as $N\to\infty$ and $\mathbf{E}[X_N]^2 \leq \mathbf{E}[X_N^2]$. This shows that the extra factor in the above bound, followed by $a_N$, converges to $1$ as $N \to \infty$:

$$ \left( 1 - \frac{m}{\mathbf{E}[X_N]}\right)_+^2 \frac{1}{1 - \mathbf{E}[X_N]/\mathbf{E}[X_N^2]} \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} 1 $$

Hence, taking $\limsup$ as $N\to\infty$ to $\text{(1)}$ gives

$$ \mathbf{P}(X_\infty > m) \geq \limsup_{N\to\infty} a_N = \alpha. $$

Now since $m$ is arbitrary, letting $m \to \infty$ shows that $ \mathbf{P}(X_\infty = \infty) \geq \alpha $, which is equivalent to the desired claim because

$$ \{ A_k \text{ i.o.}\} = \{X_{\infty} = \infty\}. $$